# jquery jquery.tagify how to add a focus effect?

Tags: jquery, focus

In my webapplication i am using tagify. But now i want that when the input box in tagify is focussed that the tagifycontainer's border-color changes to a different color.

Ive tried the most straightforward solutions but it does not work, heres what ive tried:

```
$('input[role=textbox]').focus(function(){
       alert('trigger');
       $('.tagify-container').css({
           "border-color" : "#E5964B" 
       });
});
```

I'm not getting an alert box. Ive also tried to edit the plugin but im noob at writing plugins. I mostly leech plugins ... tbh

Greets

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Basically, when tagify initializes the field:

```
$('#test').tagify();
```

It will replace:

```
<input id="test" type="text"/>
```

With something like:

```
<input id="test" style="display: none;">

<div class="tagify-container">
    <input type="text" placeholder="add tags">
</div>
```

In other words, it will hide the original field and add its own  with the field. There are many ways around it, but I used this to get the proper field:

```
$('.tagify-container:eq(0) input:eq(0)').focus(function(){
    alert('blah');      
});
```

So you select first tagify-container class and select first field in this class. Hope that works for you :)